# Editing button styles in Telerik with Bootstrap

Tags: .net, css, twitter-bootstrap, telerik

I am not a aspx coder but trying to style a button on an aspx page which uses Telerik with Bootstrap.
So, the code goes like this,

```
<telerik:RadButton CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="rbtnGiris" runat="server" Text="Giriş" OnClick="rbtnGiris_Click" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

And rendered HTML is as follows,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="RadButton RadButton_Default rbSkinnedButton" id="rbtnGiris">
<input type="submit" value="Giriş" id="rbtnGiris_input" name="rbtnGiris" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="-1">
<input type="hidden" name="rbtnGiris_ClientState" id="rbtnGiris_ClientState" autocomplete="off">
</a>
```

So as you can guess button does not look right because it is targeting an "a" element. I could not find how to change it properly.

Anyone has an idea how to manipulate lovely Telerik look? Let me know if this requires any .Net coding skills or Visual Stuido, cause I am given an .aspx page which I am editing with an Notepad++ :)

Thanx in advance

Comment: You're using a normal button css class on a radio button which won't really produce the desired results. This page indicates that possible it's too much hassle for its worth: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/twitter-bootstrap/KIwM_-T461o/WDWXVhooOcwJ

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but I see you have disabled the embedded skins and stylesheets the control comes with, so you can't really expect it to look like it should. Try setting **EnableEmbeddedSkins="true" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="true"** and see how things go.

Then, if you need to style the control further - either use a standard HTML element that will make it easier for you (you will not have to override custom CSS rules from the vendor), or examine this article to see which classes go where in a RadButton: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button_appearancecssfileselectors.html.